Spring Cloud MVC JdkClientHttpRequestFactory fail to request to http1 server
I'm using Spring Cloud mvc to build a proxy up to my https 1.1 server. Default setting is using JdkClientHttpRequestFactory HttpClient http2. I'm getting response code 400 from upstream saying that's it's mismatch http PROTO. It's likely http client can't downgrade http version to match my upstream server.
The route is working when i switch the setting to SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory by AUTODETECT:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      mvc:
        httpClient:
          type: AUTODETECT

The cause is not clearly so i'd share if someone has any idea
